# Flatpak cannot update openh264 on Linux Mint 21.1

Tags: flatpak

I am on Linux Mint 21.1, and every time I want to update my flatpaks since two weeks or so, I get this error here:

```
        KENNUNG                                     Zweig           Op           Remote            Download
 1. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264           2.0             u            flathub           1,2 MB / 1,5 MB

Warning: Während des Versuchs, zusätzliche Daten anzuwenden: Skript apply_extra ist fehlgeschlagen, Exit-Status 256
```

It obviously has to do with some obsolete and deprecated version of openh264 one of my flatpaks relies on. It says in German that while trying to apply additional data, the script apply_extra failed with exit status 256.

This seems to be a symptom of the fact that I have a flatpak installed, the maintainer of which no longer updates it.

- My question now: which flatpak could it be?
- Is there a command which can expose the culprit?
- Or would there be any other solution possible to avoid that error?

If only I knew about which flatpak(s) the system is complaining, I might also want to remove them and install different ones doing the same things, but being more up-to-date.

Comment: +1 same problem on AlmaLinux for me today